# Dryer vent hose not staying connected to the dryer vent even with clamp

Tags: dryer, vent

I cannot get the hose to stay on the metal vent coming out of the dryer.  I have tightened the clamp til I am almost bending the pipe but the venting material slides right off?
Help and thank you!

Comment: Can you add some details? A photo goes a long way on things like this...

Comment: There are many ways a Dryer hose adapter and hose can be attached - many styles of clamps too. You do not mention if this is new hose or what. Also you state what you did - but we don't really know what you did - a picture showing it is helpful . I have a simple ring clamp it compresses by itself no tightening of anything and my hose stays on - because the hose itself has to be fitted properly. A picture will help us help you. So click edit underneath your question - click the picture box and add the picture. We will be glad to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Just attach it with some small sheet metal screws.

Comment: If it is soft flexible hose like foil - that will cause it to tear.